# Filter by index and flattened in numpy, like tf.sequence_mask

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, masking

I would like to filter my array 2D with an index and then flat this array only with values in the filter. This is pretty much what tf.sequence_mask would do but I would need this in numpy or another light library.

Thanks!

PD:
This is an example:

```
array_2d = [[0,1,2,3,4,5],[8,9,10,11,12,0],[21,22,21,0,0,0]] # this is a numpy array
array_len = [6,5,3]
expected_output = [0,1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11,12,21,22,21]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `vectorized` solution, using a boolean mask to index `array_2d`:

```
array_2d = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,5],[8,9,10,11,12,0],[21,22,21,0,0,0]]) 
array_len = [6,5,3]

m = ~(np.ones(array_2d.shape).cumsum(axis=1).T > array_len).T
array_2d[m]
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 21, 22, 21])
```

**Details**

The mask is created taking the [`cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) over an ndarray of [`ones`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) of the same shape as `array_2d`, and performing a row-wise comparisson to see which elements are greater than `array_len`.

So the first step is to create the following `ndarray`:

```
np.ones(array_2d.shape).cumsum(axis=1)

array([[1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.]])
```

And perform a row-wise comparisson with `array_len`:

```
~(np.ones(array_2d.shape).cumsum(axis=1).T > array_len).T

array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False, False]])
```

Then you simply have to filter the array with:

```
array_2d[m]
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 21, 22, 21])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way using a boolean masking and applying it to your flattened `array_2d`

```
array_2d = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,5],[8,9,10,11,12,0],[21,22,21,0,0,0]]) 
array_len = [6,5,3]

# Create a boolean mask
mask = np.zeros((array_2d.shape), dtype=bool)

# Change to True for elements to be kept
for i, j in enumerate(array_len):
        mask[i][0:j] = True

expected_output = array_2d.flatten()[mask.flatten()]
```

**Output**

```
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 21, 22, 21])
```